# How to find out if a setting is stored or not on app for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings

We can use the following code to get application's setting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"settingName"]
```

But how to find out if this setting is stored or not?

P.S. I can't use special BOOL setting for that because I need to know if the exact setting is stored or not from the previous version of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `objectForKey`:

```
NSNumber *integerSetting = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"settingName"];
if (integerSetting) {
    NSInteger value = [integerSetting integerValue];
    // use value
} else {
    // setting not there
}
```

If the point of this is to set some default value then you would be better off setting a default value. Do this at the start of the app:

```
NSDictionary *defaults = @{ @"settingName" : @42 }; // set some default value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];
```

Note that registering defaults does not actually change any values. If you try to get a value that doesn't already have an explicit value, then the registered default is retrieved.

Now your code can simply be:

```
NSInteger value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"settingName"];
```

Comment: Thanks! `NSUserDefaults` (instead `NSUserDefault`) is correct on the first code.